# Sistema de postagem - "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY"

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema, na verdade não sei bem se é no PHP ou no banco de dados.

Em um sistema de postagem usando PHP, assim que você posta uma noticia, o `ID` (a primary key, que seria usada assim: `index.php?ID=0`) não esta mudando, ou seja, ela sempre começa no `0` e eu queria que começa-se a partir do `1`, e quando eu vou criar uma postagem acaba dando o seguinte erro:

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'"

e ai eu sempre tenho que mudar no MySQL para outro `ID`.

Código: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0dQEW0n1

Teria como colocar de forma sequencial?

Comment: Cola o banco de dados também... O problema está lá!

Comment: Isso quer dizer que estás a tentar inserir mais um registo com `ID=0`. Tens no banco o `ID` como *auto increment*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O seu problema provavelmente é na configuração da tabela. O campo ID tem que ser chave primária e `auto increment`. Da forma como foi feito (sem `auto increment`) o php informa `null` para o mysql que salva a `primary key` como zero toda vez que você roda seu código.

Comment: É exato. Isso ocorre sempre quando esqueco do `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters é por isso que eu crio sempre as tabelas com o workbench

Answer (score 6):

No banco de dados deves usar o `auto_increment` no ID principal. Para que ao adicionar um novo registro, já adiciona também um novo id para este registro.

```
ALTER TABLE `suatabela` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```